# Summation interchange in DFT/FFT

Tags: fft, dft

Let $x(n)$ be a sequence of length $N = LM, n = 0,\dots,N-1$.$N$ and $M$ are integers.

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of $x(n)$ is given by

$X(k) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}x(n)W^{nk}_N$

where $W_N = e^{\frac{-j 2 \pi}{N}}$.

Let $n = l + mL$ and $k = q + pM$

$0 \le l,p \le L-1$, $0 \le m,q \le M-1$

$X(p,q) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}(\sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}x(l + mL)W^{(l + mL)(q + pM)}_N)$.

$W^{(l + mL)(q + pM)}_N = W^{lq + lpM + mqL + mpLM}_N = W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N$

Since $W^N_N = 1$.

$X(p,q) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}\sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N  ... (1)$.

Why the above equation (1) can be written as
$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\{W^{lq}_N \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{mq}_M \} W^{lp}_L$

after summation interchange of indices $l$ and $m$.

Can you explain the method behind the the interchange of indices $l$ and $m$ in detail.

I have taken the above material from the book:Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications, 5th edition

https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/digital-signal-processing-principles-algorithms-and-applications/P200000003415/9780137348657

Cross posted to : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832364/summation-interchange-in-dft-fft

Comment: Generally, cross-posting is frowned upon in the SE network.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with:

$$X(p,q) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}\sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N   \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Swap the order of summation:

$$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N  \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Expand the rotator $W_N$:

$$W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N = W^{lq}_N W^{lpM}_NW^{mqL}_N \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Resulting in:

$$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq}_N W^{lpM}_NW^{mqL}_N  \tag{4}\label{4}$$

Note that $W_{LM}^{Lx}=W_M^x$ so replace $N=LM$ when $W_N$ is raised to an exponent with $L$ or $M$ in it to factor it out:

$$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq}_N W^{lpM}_{LM}W^{mqL}_{LM}   \tag{5}\label{5}$$

$$= \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq}_N W^{lp}_{L}W^{mq}_{M}   \tag{6}\label{6}$$

We can pull out of the summation any terms that are not dependent on the variable being summed:

$$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\{W^{lq}_N \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{mq}_M \} W^{lp}_L\tag{7}\label{7}$$

---

The OP mentioned in the comments about being confused on the justification for swapping the order of the summations. This is the commutative property of addition and multiplication, where changing the order of the addends does not change the sum, and changing the order of the factors does not change the product. This holds as long as the summations converge. Here is a simple demonstration:

$$Y=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} m n$$

$$=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} m (n_0+n_1+n_2+\ldots n_{N-1})$$

$$=(n_0+n_1+n_2+\ldots n_{N-1})\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} m $$

$$=(n_0+n_1+n_2+\ldots n_{N-1})(m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots m_{M-1}) $$

it should be clear that this is equal to:

$$Y=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} m n$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots m_{N-1})n$$

$$=(m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots m_{N-1})\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} n$$

$$=(m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots m_{M-1})(n_0+n_1+n_2+\ldots n_{N-1}) $$

$$=(n_0+n_1+n_2+\ldots n_{N-1})(m_0+m_1+m_2+\ldots m_{M-1}) $$

Comment: Regarding 'Swap the order of summation' Can I simply swap summation order or not. Why it is justified.

Comment: It's given by the commutative property: you can add or multiply addends or factors in any order to get the same total (when the summations converge as they do always here given the finite duration). For a proof to the general case see https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/twosum.pdf

Comment: I also added a simple example to the bottom of this answer that should clear that up.